# AccessRules - доступ в админку

Tags: yii

Я установил роли для своего проекта и тут столкнулся с вопросом.

В контроллере админ панели, я прописал вот такие вот правила:

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(

        array('allow',
            'actions'=>array(),
            'roles'=>array('administrator')
        ),

         array('allow',
            'actions'=>array('error'),
            'roles'=>array('*'),
        ),

        array('deny',
            'actions'=>array('index'),
            'roles'=>array('*'),
        ),

        array('deny',
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ), 
    );
}
```

Однако из-за

```
        array('deny',
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
```

Никто в админку не имеет доступа, хотя если убрать именно это правило, то все вроде работает как нужно. Однако как-то стремно по безопасности. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что как?

Answer (score 1):

А почему у тебя массив 'actions' пустой у 'roles'=>array('administrator')?
непонятно, к чему у него есть доступ..

Я бы убрал

```
 array('allow',
            'actions'=>array('error'),
            'roles'=>array('*'),
        ),

       array('deny',
           'actions'=>array('index'),
           'roles'=>array('*'),
       ),
```

оставив только первый и последний. У меня в проекте так работает - вполне норм

Comment: array('deny',
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),

из-за конкретно этого не пускает. У меня у пользователя есть поле группа и там: administrator

и безнес роль
return Yii::app()->user->role=="administrator";